# Microsoft Graph API: Subscribing to MailboxSettings

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to subscribe to changes of MailboxSettings - specifically AutomaticRepliesSetting?

Trying to POST this to `/subscriptions` on the beta API.

```
{
   "changeType":"updated",
   "notificationUrl":"https://example.com/microsoft/notify",
   "resource":"users/karel@example.com/mailboxSettings",
   "expirationDateTime":"2018-05-11T08:05:26.6920740Z",
   "clientState":"QUUvRXJ5beHI9VEvn6hq"
}
```

Getting back:

```
"code": "ExtensionError",     
"message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]"
```

The application has admin consent for `Calendars.ReadWrite`, `User.Read.All` and `MailboxSettings.ReadWrite`

I can successfully subscribe to calendar changes, so nothing is wrong with the implementation.

Subscribing to the root `/users/karel@example.com` endpoint gives:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: InternalServerError; Reason: Internal Server Error]",
    "innerError": { "request-id": "3caffc72-9507-4bb7-9eab-56e8ecaaab83", "date": "2018-05-08T09:22:16" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Subscribing to the root `/users/karel@example.com` endpoint gives: `"error": {     "code": "ExtensionError",     "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: InternalServerError; Reason: Internal Server Error]",     "innerError": {       "request-id": "3caffc72-9507-4bb7-9eab-56e8ecaaab83",       "date": "2018-05-08T09:22:16"     }   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks):

> Using the Microsoft Graph REST API, an app can subscribe to changes on the following resources:
>
> - Messages
> - Events
> - Contacts
> - Users
> - Groups
> - Group conversations
> - Content shared on OneDrive including drives associated with SharePoint sites
> - User's personal OneDrive folders

Comment: This is under the `/users` resource endpoint though? From the documentation it should be supported?

Comment: You can subscribe to `/users` (changes to the AAD), that isn't the same as subscribing to `/mailboxSettings` (changes to an Exchange mailbox).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Any plans for supporting this anytime soon? It makes sense to not have to poll for out of office/automatic replies.

Comment: I'm not aware of any but I could certainly put it into the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com)